# Динамическое добавление элементов в RecycleView

Tags: android

С сервера приходит кол-во блоков, в каждом блоке какая то информация. Как добавлять произвольное количество блоков,  которое приходит с сервера в RecycleView?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте `recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` после редактирования контейнера с данными.

Или `recyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemChanged(ElementIndex)` если хотите обновить какой-то определенный элемент.

Answer (score 2):

Создайте в адаптере метод для добавления данных. В нём добавляйте данные в список и обновите его отображение через `notifyDataSetChanged()` или `notifyItemChanged()`.

```
private void addItem(MyItem item) {    
    itemArrayList.add(item);
    notifyItemChanged(itemArrayList.size()-1);
}
```